# Where would I query the ticket classification attributes from?

Tags: json, rest, url, integration, maximo

If I want to retrieve the data of a service request in Maximo, I can use the following URL:

`https://<domain>/maxrest/rest/os/mxsr?ticketid=12345&_format=json`

I query this URL from outside of a browser and use this data for external storage and data handling. While this provides me with a lot of information, it does not give me everything that browsing the ticket 'the usual way' would. When loading a ticket from the Service Requests (SP) application, I get a Specifications tab with attributes that's missing from the ticket's JSON.

A redacted example:

[image: Example]

Pressing Alt + F1 on the value of either key, like Workcenter, produces the following help:

[image: Ticketspec]

I suppose the ticketspec is a secondary field or type of field that's somehow linked to the Service Request. However, I have not been able to find a way to retrieve the data inside this Specifications/Attributes/Ticketspec field. I strongly suspect it's what Maximo calls [Ticket classifications](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/mfsp/7.6.2?topic=application-ticket-classifications), but I'm not 100% certain on that.

How can I find the URL for this information, provided I have the `ticketid`? Or is there no URL available at all?

I had hoped to find the answer in the apimeta (`https://<domain>/maxrest/oslc/apimeta`), but with over 500 results I'm not knowledgeable enough how to turn that into an answer.

While I know my way around Maximo and the API, I am not an administrator. Thus should be from a user or poweruser's perspective. I can not modify what data is being served or how. Feel free to leave comments asking for clarification and I'll do my best to answer them.

Answer (score 0):

So in that url you are using, you are using the MXSR object structure to retrieve results.  That object structure - as shipped from IBM - includes the SR object only, and no subsidiary tables such as TICKETSPEC.

You can duplicate MXSR (don't modify it), and add TICKETSPEC as a source object.  Specify SR as the parent, and TICKETSPEC as your relationship.

While in Object Stuctures, you can exclude/include fields to reduce the amount of information you're getting back from Maximo.

Comment: I can not modify the data structure, as I am not an administrator. I can retrieve the TICKETID and TICKETUID from the JSON. Can I retrieve the data from a subsidiary table using the REST API? What would be the place to start looking? I haven't found any references in the API guide.

Comment: There currently is no object structure with the name TICKETSPEC. I can not duplicate objects or add relationships, I can only query existing data.

Comment: Was any part of my question unclear?

Comment: without an Object Structure I don't think there's a way to get that data via API.   In an as-shipped Maximo system I don't believe there is an Object Structure that gives access to TICKETSPEC.  It sounds like you have no ability to get an object structure created for you - it's fairly routine to create object structures as part of configuration.

Comment: I assume the structure must exist somewhere, since it shows up for every SR with this classification.